# Use variable with the EOF to generate a file

Tags: bash

I am trying to generate a .js file based on the shell variable following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17983608/837059) SO. However, the script still create the file with `APP_VERSION: $bumped_version`

This is my script:

```
version=9.9.9

cat > ./constant/app.js <<'msg'
export default Object.freeze({
  APP_VERSION: $bumped_version
})
msg
```

generated app.js:

```
export default Object.freeze({
  APP_VERSION: $bumped_version
})
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Remove the quotes from msg which specifically says, do not expand any variables or wild cards.

Comment: @grail Ah... thanks, went into the wrong direction just now. Can you answer the question so I can mark it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heredocs can be used in a few different ways:

1. Standard - this allows for expansion of parameters, but must have closing word hard against left edge:

`cat <<EOF
  ...
EOF`

2. Indented - here you can use tabs to indent both text and closing word

`cat <<-EOF
 [tab][tab]...
 [tab]EOF`

3. Quoted - this version prevents any expansions from being done, which can be useful if you are using it to create another script with variables.
   If outputting to a file, all the tabs at the start of each line will be removed

`cat <<'EOF'
  ...
 EOF`

You can also combine 2 and 3.